# Linq To excel cant find column in excel

Tags: c#, linq, excel

I am using Linq to Excel  library to get acces to one of excel sheets, the problem which i got into is, that my call cant fin a column with specifik name.

```
public IQueryable<Cell> getExcel()
    {

        var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory();
        excel.FileName = @"C:\Users\Timsen\Desktop\QUOTATION.CSV";
        var indianaCompanies = from c in excel.Worksheet() select c["ARTICLE TEXT"];

        return indianaCompanies;

    }
```

**Error :**

base {System.SystemException} = {"'ARTICLE TEXT' column name does not exist. Valid column names are 'QUOT NO;DEBTOR;ITEM;ART NO;HWS NO#;BRANCH PRICE;QTY;PR;ARTICLE T', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5'"}

**Name of tables in Excell**

QUOT

NO

DEBTOR

ITEM

ART

NO

HWS

NO.

BRANCH PRICE

QTY

PR

ARTICLE TEXT

TYPE NAME

SALES PRICE

QT%

DIS

AMOUNT

UNI

B

ARTG

SUPPL

DUTY

UPDAte Sample of Excel : 
[image]

Comment: ARTICLE TEXT is being referenced in the error log as ARTICLE T . Did you try that?

Comment: Well i can see that, but how to fix it? in Excel name is ARTICLE TEXT but it looks like linqtoexcel just return only part of column text name

Comment: I am familiar with `ExelQueryFactory` library, but have you tried using [OledbDataAdapter](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2008/02/29/getting-data-from-excel-the-fast-way-using-linq.aspx)?

Comment: @AnuragRanjhan - Can we not suggest solutions that use JET which WILL NOT and CANNOT WORK in the future on x64 operating systems? He should either use ACE or use the method he is using.  His current problem is a malformed header values I suspect.

Comment: @Ramhound I was not aware JET was not going work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show us the first line or two of the csv file?

If I'm interpreting the error message correctly, the header line has semicolons instead of commas for separators.

Specifically, the error message appears to list these as the column names (note that it's using single quotes and commas to try and make it clear, which seems useful).

1. 'QUOT NO;DEBTOR;ITEM;ART NO;HWS NO#;BRANCH PRICE;QTY;PR;ARTICLE T'
2. 'F2'
3. 'F3'
4. 'F4'
5. 'F5'

Since that first column name is 64 characters, I'm assuming it cut off at that point and the rest of the columns would be in there as well (still semicolon-delimited) if that limit wasn't in place.

Not sure off-hand if you can specify a different delimiter with the linq-to-excel project or not, since it appears to use Jet for csv files, as per https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel/blob/792e0807b2cf2cb6b74f55565ad700d2fcf31e19/src/LinqToExcel/Query/ExcelUtilities.cs

If making it a 'real' csv isn't an option and the library doesn't support specifying an alternate delimiter, you might just be able to get the articles text by going through the lines in the file (except the first) and pull out the 12th column (since that appears to be the article text).

So, something like:

```
var articleTextValues =
    // Skip(1) since we don't want the header
    from line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Timsen\Desktop\QUOTATION.CSV").Skip(1)
    select line.Split(';')[11];
```

Comment: I was hoping for the actual contents of the lines, not so much how Excel looks when it loads them.  Is the file actually text-based and comma-separated values?  The linq-to-excel library chooses the engine to use based on extension, so if the file isn't actual csv data, you'll need to rename it to the right extension for the library to handle it correctly.

Comment: Since you're able to load the file into Excel, one thing you could do to fix this is to re-save the file from Excel into a 'real' csv file (using commas as separators).  One other possibility is that you have a regional setting of a different character than comma as your list separator - if that's the case, you might want to try changing it to comma long enough to save the file contents as actual comma-separated.  If this doesn't need to be automated, then you could also just save the file as a real Excel workbook and use that since it'll avoid the separators issue completely.

Comment: well when they save it from CiCS database it will be saved as a .XLS file, could that be a problem, soi have to resave the file to .csv format?

Comment: Okay i solved it now, problem was file format. Apprently if the same file with th same data is in CSV format, it will get problem as i did. But as soon, as u transfer format type into XLS file, problem is gone, everything works PERFECT! James thatnk for help, your answers got me in right direction ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
public IQueryable<Cell> getExcel() 
{ 

    var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(); 
    excel.FileName = @"C:\Users\Timsen\Desktop\QUOTATION.CSV"; 
    var indianaCompanies = from c in excel.Worksheet() select c["ARTICLE T"]; 

    return indianaCompanies; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It lists the valid column names.  It is having problems with some of the headers for the columns indicated by the fact **QTY;PR;** means it parsed two different columns instead of one.  F2 indicates it does not know what the header should actually be called.

The simplest solution is to verify the data being imported into the following query matches your excel document.

```
var indianaCompanies = from c in excel.Worksheet() select *;
```

I believe that will work.

Comment: QTy and PR is different columns (i failed at formatting). well it will get whole sheet, but how do i extract data from only ARTICLE TEXT coulmn?